# Adding userPrincipalName with a script

Tags: typescript, powershell, active-directory

I have a CSV file contains all of my test script AD users. The CSV file contains all of the following information:

- ID number
- First Name
- Last Name
- SamAccountName
- OU Path

The users were created. Some of these users do not have **userPrincipalName** all other attributes are fine.

I want to write s script which will add **userPrincipalName** to all users.

What I tried:

```
$CSVusers = import-csv C:\CorpCSV.csv
$Users = $CSVusers.SamAccountName
$Users | % {Get-ADUser $_ | Set-ADUser $_ -userPrincipalName $Users}
```

I did not get any errors, but it seems like nothing happened. The attribute is still empty on AD. (See attached).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what the desired UserPrincipleName should be.
It seems that this is not part of your input CSV file.
Usually the UserPrincipleName is `sAMAccountName@DnsDomainName`

If the users are all in the same domain you are logged in to, you can construct the domain name part using `$env:USERDNSDOMAIN` or `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($env:COMPUTERNAME).HostName`

```
$CSVusers = Import-Csv C:\PollogenCSV.csv
# get an array of just the sAMAccountNames
$Users = $CSVusers.SamAccountName
$Domain = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN  # or use [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($env:COMPUTERNAME).HostName
$Users | ForEach-Object { 
    # construct the UserPrincipalName
    $upn = "{0}@{1}" -f $_, $Domain
    Get-ADUser $_ | Set-ADUser -UserPrincipalName $upn
}
```

Comment: So what this line will do? “{0}@{1}” ??

Comment: @RoyW The `"{0}@{1}"` is just a way of forming a string from different parts. It is a template string with placeholders `{0}`, `{1}` etc. The placeholders are then replaced by the variables you put after the `-f` Format operator in order. I could also have done: `$upn = "$_@$Domain"` or `$upn = $_ + '@' + $Domain`, but I just happen to like the `"{0}@{1}"` way because it is concise and to me it makes easy reading of the code. Have a look [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/11/understanding-powershell-and-basic-string-formatting/) to learn about String Formatting.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response!